# Get Order ID in Abstract.php PDF protected function insertLogo

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have been banging my head against a brick wall for the last 2 hours.

I am editing app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.pdf.

All I am trying to achieve is a little if statement so that based on a particular payment method I can change what image is used on the invoice header.

I have tried evrything but cannot get the OrderID inside the

```
protected function insertLogo{}
```

Any advice would be great.

Thankyou.

Comment: why are you editing vendor code? you are yusing the wrong approach. why not extend the class? protected properties are available from the child class

Comment: So how would I go about doing that?

Comment: without seeing your code, no one can help you

Comment: My code is just the standard code. I just made a copy and moved to the local.

Comment: great. we have no idea what standard code you mean.

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.pdf.

Comment: I can't even edit the post to show you.

Comment: I don't have that file. Where online is it?

Comment: https://github.com/adam-paterson/magento-ce-1.9.0.1/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

Comment: what class are you really dealing with? that is an abstract class, something definitely extends it

Comment: I do not know. I was messing with the `protected function insertLogo{}` part if that helps.

Comment: So going off this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205890/override-order-pdf-abstract-model-from-custom-module it appears that the order_pdf_creditmemo , order_pdf_invoice, order_pdf_shipment and order_pdf_shipment_packaging extend it

Comment: So he should extend whichever of those classes he is actually working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I took another tact with this.

I cloned the insertLogo function and named it insertLogo2.

The first had one image and insertLogo2 contained the second.

I then added the if statement to the app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php.

I know it's not pretty but it works for me.